# One time login in app - FirebaseAuth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app that uses Firebase authentication to sign in users through phone number. I want to add a functionality such that there is only one-time login for the user, i.e. even if the user kills the app and starts it again, he should be logged in. Also, I don't want to add a logout feature. What can be done for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a listener. Let's assume you have two activities, the `LoginActivity` and the `MainActivity`. The listener that can be created in the `LoginActivity` should look like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

This basically means that if the user is logged in, skip the `LoginActivity` and go to the `MainActivity`.

Instantiate the `FirebaseAuth` object:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

And start listening for changes in your `onStart()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

In the `MainActivity`, you should do the same thing:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
```

Which basically means that if the user is not logged in, skip the `MainActivity` and go to the `LoginActivity`. In this activity you should do the same thing as in the `LoginActivity`, you should start listening for changes in the `onStart()`.

In both activities, don't forget to remove the listener in the moment in which is not needed anymore. So add the following line of code in your `onStop()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! But I think shared preferences too would be good to use.

Comment: It would be if don't care about app uninstall. `SharedPreferences` do not persist across app uninstall while Firebase keeps authentication data in a back-up even if the application is deleted. So in this case, if you uninstall the app, there will be no loss of informations. It's up to you to decide which solution is better for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex! Actually I'm making an app for visually impaired people, and using now I realize that using authStateListener will be the right decision.

Comment: I have tried your method but after uninstalling the app, the app still requires the user to authenticate. What went wrong, any idea?

Comment: Is the cache set to true in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: How do you set that? I couldn't find any such feature there. However, `android:allowBackup` was already set to `true`.

Comment: This `android:fullBackupContent="true"` should also be set to `true`.

Comment: Are you sure you are not signing out somehow?

Comment: And you haven't added other sign-in method like google, right?

Comment: No, I haven't. Authentication is only through the phone number.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot tel you more that the Firebase authentication session is persisted on the user's device in the Android back-up, as explained above. This data for the application is not removed when the application is uninstalled.

Answer (score 3):

You can save user login session in shared Preference

Do this when your login got Login Success

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.commit();
```

and When Your apps is Starts (like Splash or login Page) use this

```
 SharedPreferences sp=this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  boolean b = sp.getBoolean("key_name", false);
if(b==true){
//User Already Logged in skip login page and continue to next process
}else{
//User is Not logged in, show login Form
}
```

It will works for you.

Comment: what is the strFile parameter here?

Comment: It is the preference Name, i forget to change it ,now i updated answer @Einzig7

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error here for the getBoolean function, it says that getBoolean has two parameters, a string and a boolean.

Comment: It wants a default value set it false

Comment: Happy to help , happy Coding  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is from my working code from logging class:

```
   private void LoginUserAccount(String email, String password)
{
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ResponseStartPage.this, "Please write Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ResponseStartPage.this, "Please write Your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Login Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait for verification...");
        loadingBar.show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    String DeviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                    usersReference.child(online_user_id).child("device_token").setValue(DeviceToken)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                                {
                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ResponseStartPage.this, ResponseMainActivity.class);
                                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });


                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ResponseStartPage.this, "Please Check your email and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```