# Deleting Firebase User and Going back to login

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

I am creating a Firebase Project whis has a Settings option in the Navigation drawer, in which there is a button to delete the user. If the user clicks the button i show him my alert dialog and if he presses yes, i want him to be deleted from the Firebase Database and also as a user, toast a message and move back to login screen. Everything works but after I intent to my Login.class if i click the back button it moves me back to the settings tab, as if the user is still signed in (but he is not, its deleted). Is there a way to finish that fragment in order to not be able to go back there? This is my code.

**FragmentSettings.class**

```
public class FragmentSettings extends Fragment {

Button delete, change, rateus;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    delete = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete your account? This will permanently delete all of your information.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //Deleting user info from database
                            mDatabase.getReference().child(user.getUid()).removeValue();
                            //Deleting user.
                            user.delete();
                            //Signing out and back to login.
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Login.class);
                            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                            if(fragment != null)
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
    });
    change = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_change);
    change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeFragment();
        }
    });
    rateus = v.findViewById(R.id.settings_rateus);
    rateus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "App will be in App-Store soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void changeFragment() {
    FragmentChangePassword newChangePasswordFragment = new FragmentChangePassword();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newChangePasswordFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `finish()` after calling the intent to login activity. Like this:

```
//Signing out and back to login.
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Login.class);
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if(fragment != null)
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```