# setIsSmartLockEnabled(false) is not working in FirebaseUI Lib

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

In my app there are two type of users "Viewer" and "Controller" so my app starts with an activity where user select user type (`UserTypeActivity`). I want to show this activity only if user is not signed in to app. In Its on start method I'm checking if the user is signed in or not based on this I send the user to `MainActivity` or `signInActivity` Now when a user click logout button from `mainActivity`I redirect it to this `UserTypeActivity` because user can switch between viewer and controller. The problem is when I sign out the user according to the API's documentation the `UserTypeActivity` send the user to `MainActivity` saying user is already logged in.
I'm Using this code for logout.

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            // user is now signed out
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityViewer.this,
                                    UserTypeActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
```

When signing in I have set the `.setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)` I'm using `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` approach for signing in. So please let me know how can I prevent the app to Auto-SignIn if user press logout button. Also let me know if any other code part I have to show.
Regards

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out.

Comment: Thanks, I did not removed Auth Listener in `UserTypeActivity`.