# Check if is user first login on Android App using Firebase Auth and Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

**I am making an chat app and I want to do the following:**

When starting the MainActivity, check if the user is logged in. If not, start FirebaseAuthUI.

But FirebaseAuth only supports a few parameters and, to add more, I created a Database node do each user, which store other parameters. 
To get this parameters, after finishing FirebaseAuth, the user is redirected to an Activity that get all extra information and store in the user's node in the Database. All of this is working just fine.

But after the user fill the information in this Info Activity and finish the register, it should go back to MainActivity and stay there. How can I do that?

**I am trying it this way:**

I added to each user a Boolean variable called `userCompleted`, which informs if the user have already gave their information. I check if this variable is false, and if so, I call the Info Activity intent and, in the when the user press the button to complete the registration in this Activity, it sets the `userCompleted` value to `true` in the user node in the Database and then start an intent that leads to MainActivity.

The problem is that in the Database, `userCompleted` is set to `true` and then immediately goes back to `false`, and I don't know why. Also, I guess I am having trouble on reading `userCompleted` from the Database, probably because I haven't worked much with asynchronous tasks.

I used a variable `isUserCompleted` declared in Main Activity to get track of the userCompleted value.

A way to check if is the first time the user is logging in would be useful too, although it wouldn't solve my whole problem.

**This is my current code:**

(if need more to try to understand the problem just ask in the comments)

*Create AuthStateListener*

```
public void setAuthStateListener(){
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                onSignInInitialize(user);
                Log.d(TAG, "userUid = " + user.getUid());
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                onSignOutCleanup();
                startLoginUI();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

*onSignInInitialize()*

```
public void onSignInInitialize(final FirebaseUser user){
    mLoggedFBUser = user;
    mUserReference = mUsersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid());
    mUserReference.child("uid").setValue(user.getUid());

    mUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            isUserCompleted = user.isUserCompleted();
            Log.d(TAG, "UserCompleted (onDataChanged) "+ isUserCompleted);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "UserCompleted (Before startActivity if) "+ isUserCompleted);

    if (!isUserCompleted) {
        startCreateProfileActivity(user);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "UserCompleted (After startActivity if) "+ isUserCompleted);

    mUserReference.child("username").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
    mUserReference.child("email").setValue(user.getEmail());

    attachChildEventListener();
}
```

*Go back to Main Activity*

```
mFinishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mUserDatabaseReference.child("userCompleted").setValue(true);
            Intent intent = new Intent (CreateVolunteerProfile.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

---

**Entire MainActivity block (Actually it's called `SearchActivity`)**

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerAdapter.UserItemClickListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

private String mLoggedUserId = "user2";
private String mLoggedUsername;
private User mLoggedUser;
private FirebaseUser mLoggedFBUser;
//private boolean isUserCompleted;

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mPreferencesEditor;
private boolean firstTime = true;

private static final String TAG = "Search Activity";
private static final int USER_CLICK = 1;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final int RC_CREATE_PROFILE = 2;

//Firebase
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabaseReference;
private DatabaseReference mUserReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    View loadingView = findViewById(R.id.cl_loading);
    loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //RecyclerView
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_users);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(users, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Firebase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUsersDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");

    setAuthStateListener();

    loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null)
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    detachChildEventListener();
    clearAdapter();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState userId = "+ mLoggedUserId);
    //Log.wtf(TAG, "UserCompleted (onSaveInstanceState) " + isUserCompleted);
    outState.putString("userId", mLoggedUserId);
    //outState.putBoolean("isUserCompleted", isUserCompleted);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mLoggedUserId = savedInstanceState.getString("userId");
    //isUserCompleted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isUserCompleted");
    //Log.wtf(TAG, "UserCompleted (onRestoreInstanceState) " + isUserCompleted);
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState userId = "+ mLoggedUserId);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if((requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) && firstTime){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    if((requestCode == RC_CREATE_PROFILE)){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //isUserCompleted = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onUserItemClick(int clickedUserIndex) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, ChatActivity.class);

    FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(user !=  null) {
        mLoggedUserId = user.getUid();
        intent.putExtra("user1", mLoggedUserId);

        String mUserRecieverId = users.get(clickedUserIndex).getUid();
        intent.putExtra("user2", mUserRecieverId);

        Log.wtf(TAG, "SearchActivity // user = " + users.get(clickedUserIndex));
        Log.wtf("1", "SearchActivity // mLoggedUserId = " + mLoggedUserId + " // users.getUid() = " + users.get(clickedUserIndex).getUid());

        startActivityForResult(intent, USER_CLICK);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void setAuthStateListener(){
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                mUserReference = mUsersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid());
                onSignInInitialize(user);

                Log.wtf(TAG, "userUid = " + user.getUid());

                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                onSignOutCleanup();
                startLoginUI();
            }
        }
    };
}

public void onSignInInitialize(final FirebaseUser user){
    mLoggedFBUser = user;
    mUserReference = mUsersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid());
    mUserReference.child("uid").setValue(user.getUid());
    boolean isUserCompleted = false;

    mUserReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            isUserCompleted = user.isUserCompleted();
            Log.wtf(TAG, "UserCompleted (onDataChanged) "+ isUserCompleted);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Log.wtf(TAG, "UserCompleted (Before startActivity if) "+ isUserCompleted);

    if (!isUserCompleted) {
        startCreateProfileActivity(user);
    }
    Log.wtf(TAG, "UserCompleted (After startActivity if) "+ isUserCompleted);

    mUserReference.child("username").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
    mUserReference.child("email").setValue(user.getEmail());

    attachChildEventListener();
}

public void onSignOutCleanup(){
    mLoggedUser = null;
    mLoggedUserId = null;
    mLoggedUsername = null;
    detachChildEventListener();
    clearAdapter();
}

public void attachChildEventListener(){
    if (mChildEventListener == null){
        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                users.add(user);
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded userId = "+ user.getUid());
                //adapter.notifyItemInserted(users.size()-1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) { }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        };
    }

    mUsersDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
}

public void detachChildEventListener(){
    if (mChildEventListener != null){
        mUsersDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mChildEventListener = null;
    }
}

public void clearAdapter() {
    final int size = users.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            users.remove(0);
        }
        adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
}

public void startCreateProfileActivity(FirebaseUser user){
    mUsersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("userCompleted").setValue(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUid());
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_CREATE_PROFILE);
}

public void startLoginUI(){
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .setLogo(R.mipmap.logo)
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                            //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
                            //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
                            //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GitHubBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()))
                    //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                    //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.AnonymousBuilder().build()))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.sign_out_item:
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could u please share your MainActivity code block for Checking?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out. It might help you.

Comment: @mohammedmahmoud just added the code block, any doubts just ask

Comment: @AlexMamo this helped a lot! Does not completely solve my problem since if the user log out then log in again they will see the screen again, and they shouldn't. But I think I can handle it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is if a user clicked on finish Btn successfully  make a flag with true else make it false

in your `MainActivity`

```
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

             // User signed in and not registered 
              if (user&&!isPressedOnFinishBtn) {
                // User is signed in.
              }
         user clicked on finish btn 
          else if(isPressedOnFinishBtn) {
                // No user is signed in.
              }
            });
```

Comment: where do I declare isPressedOnFinishBtn so I will be able to change its value in an activity and check its value in another one?

Comment: Yes sure declare  it the MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that . 
Create a method inside your Login activity .

```
 private void AllowUserToLogin() {
    String userName = userEmail.getText().toString();
    String userPass = userPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter user Name / password first . . .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        dialogBar.setTitle("Sign In ");
        dialogBar.setMessage("Please Wait . . .");
        dialogBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialogBar.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, userPass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            String deviceToken = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                            UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("device_token")
                                    .setValue(deviceToken)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                sendUserToMainActivity();
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Logged in Successfull . . . ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                dialogBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });


                        } else {
                            String error = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Wrong Email or Password: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialogBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and on ur onClick() method .

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == needNewAccount) {
        sendUserToRegisterActivity();
    } else if (v == loginButton) {
        AllowUserToLogin();
    }else if(v == phone_button){
        Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this , PhoneLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);

    }

}
```

this is sendUserToRegisterActivity()

```
private void sendUserToRegisterActivity() {
    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, RegisterationForm.class);
    startActivity(registerIntent);
}
```

This is sendUserToMainActivity() .

```
 private void sendUserToMainActivity() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```