# Endless loop in onStart()

Tags: java, android, onstart

Why am I getting an endless loop between the main activity and login activity?

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuthListener == null) {
            //removeAuthSateListner is used in onStart function just for checking purposes, it helps in logging you out.
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        } else
            startActivity(new Intent(this, EditProfileActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: What does your login activity look like? Is there code routing back to the main activity?

Comment: yes and am really get crazy looking for a way to stop this loop :( , i will post both main and login codes now ,check updated

Comment: Your question is incomplete, need the code of your login Activity to help solve the problem.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out.