# Show signIn when user log out from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-navigation

In my fragment i have dialog(with log out), when user click he log out from app:

```
override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(requireContext())
}
```

But after that, I want to send the user to the authorization fragment, in my case this is `MainFragment`.

So i added next code in my `nav_graph`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settings_list_fragment"
    android:name="com.mandarine.targetList.features.settings.SettingsListFragment"
    android:label="@string/settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_list" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_list_fragment_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment" />
</fragment>
```

Also add line in my function `onClick()`:

```
override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(requireContext())
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_settings_list_fragment_to_mainFragment)
    }
```

But always when i move to `MainFragment` my user `isn't null`.

Only if I kill the app then the user is `null`.

Here is code of my `MainFragment`:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mAuthStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "MainFragment"
        const val SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        signIn()
        launchSignInFlow()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        auth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener)
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mAuthStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
                Log.d("some", "user not null")
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.show_goals)
            } else {
                Log.d("some", "null")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE) {
            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // User successfully signed in
                Log.i(TAG, "Successfully signed in user ${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName}!")
            } else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in unsuccessful ${response?.error?.errorCode}")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun launchSignInFlow() {
        // Give users the option to sign in / register with their email
        // If users choose to register with their email,
        // they will need to create a password as well
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )

        // Create and launch sign-in intent.
        // We listen to the response of this activity with the
        // SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE code
        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),
             SIGN_IN_RESULT_CODE
        )
    }
}
```

**UPD**:
For example if i change my onClick in `SettingsListFragment` all works is correct:

```
override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(requireContext())
    activity?.finish()
}
```

But I don't want the user to exit my app

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out but instead of sending the user to a new activity, navigate to an existing fragment. If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: @AlexMamo hm but i didn't sending the user to a new activity, i want to navigate him in my existing fragment:`MainFragment`. 
Also i didn t want to use MVVM in this project, i using MVP

Comment: That was what I'm saying, instead of sending the user to an activity simply navigate to the desired fragment.

Comment: @AlexMamo so?)) i write that i m tried to send user to fragment with this line
`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_settings_list_fragment_to_mainFragment)`

From one fragment to another fragment

Comment: That's correct. Aren't you getting to the desired fragment?

Comment: @AlexMamo yep, in my `MainFragment`, but the user I have is not null. Also u can check my method `signIn`

Comment: @AlexMamo after I click log out
I expect to see an authorization window in `MainFragment` since the user is my `null`
instead I get the same user...

Comment: So you say that you are still authenticated even if you logout?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, only if I don't kill the app. Maybe he does not have time so quickly to get out of the system, and I throw in another fragment? I don t know

Comment: @AlexMamo mb u have some ideas?

Comment: No idea so far.

Comment: Also, I created a task, mb the full picture will be able to help answer the question, thereby helping me to deal with the problem https://github.com/mnewlive/make-it/issues/30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my `nav_graph.xml`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settings_list_fragment"
    android:name="com.mandarine.targetList.features.settings.SettingsListFragment"
    android:label="@string/settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_list">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/sign_in"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"/>
</fragment>
```

And add next code:

```
override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
    activity?.let {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(it).addOnCompleteListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.sign_in)
        }
    }
}
```

That is solved my problem.