# How to check for a phone auth user in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, onstart

How to modify this `onStart()` method to get my separate Phone auth user database?

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
     if(what condition required to check for phone auth){
        startActivity(new Intent(EnterAs.this, UI_Main_User.class));
        finish();
    } else {
       for email auth users
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by calling UserInfo's [getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-abstract-list-extends-userinfo-getproviderdata-) method on the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object, to get the list of all authentication providers that are used by the authenticated user. One more thing to note is that each [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) class contains a method named [getProviderId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo#getProviderId()) which returns the ID of the provider.

A workable solution in code might look like this:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
List<? extends UserInfo> userInfos = firebaseUser.getProviderData();
for (UserInfo userInfo : userInfos) {
    String providerId = userInfo.getProviderId();
    if (providerId.equals(PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
        //Your logic goes here
    }
}
```

If in the future you'll use for example, [Google authentication with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), then you should check against:

```
GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked like heaven but is using for loop a great idea in Onstart as it can produce a significant delay on my activity to start

Comment: That loop it's a simple loop, should not produce a significant delay. Maybe there are other elements in the code that produce that.

Comment: In my case FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() is null the user has logged out from firebase. How can i check if is registered in the database?

Comment: @cousma In that case you need an [auth listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth).

Comment: @AlexMamo The authListener checks if the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() is null and if it is, it directs the user to loginActivity and if it's not directs to MainActivity. What i need is when the user has logged out from firebase in th app (i do it by FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() ) and tries to use the app again i want to check if the user has registered with Firebase - if they are registered i want to login them by typing their password but if not i want to make a phone authentication with OTP, so show them an OtpView and do the phone authentication. How to check that?

Comment: @cousma You cannot do that. You cannot authenticate a user, only the user does.

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't want to authenticate the user, i want to check if the user exists in the database that's all. if it exists i don't want to do phone authentication again this should happen only once when they register, if the user exists in the database i want to just type their password and login. But the problem is how will i check if the user is phone registered in Firebase.

Comment: @cousma Add user data in Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore and check that before doing some action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211737/discussion-between-cousma-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: @AlexMamo Could you elaborate a bit more please? I am adding data in the Realtime Database.
This is an example of an entry in my realtime database
Auto-Generated ID
+16505553434:
"some@email.com"
email:
"some@email.com"
first name:
"First name"
last name:
"Last name"
phone:
"+16505553434"

Comment: @cousma These are questions that are not related to this one. Add a new question so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexMamo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236899/how-to-check-when-a-user-has-phone-authenticated-in-firebase