# Failed to import import Fire-base authentication (ProviderQueryResult com.google.firebase.auth.ProviderQueryResult; )

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Android Studio and Andoridx
I am trying to import the following class

> `import com.google.firebase.auth.ProviderQueryResult;`

the Error I get is

> **Cannot Resolve symbol 'ProviderQueryResult'**

I need to check to see if the email is not already present in the database Using but cannot execute because the** `import com.google.firebase.auth.ProviderQueryResult;`** is Not Working.

```
                                         @Override
                                         public void onComplete(@NonNullTask<ProviderQueryResult>task{
                                             if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                  getProviders().size() will return size 1 if email ID is in use.
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: RESULT: " + task.getResult().getProviders().size());
                                                 if (task.getResult().getProviders().size() == 1) {
                                                     Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: That email is already in use.");
                                                     hideDialog();
                                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "That email is already in use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} 
else {
                                                     Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: That email is available.");
}
```

I tried - invalidate catches and restart but no Changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation, the [ProviderQueryResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/ProviderQueryResult) interface is deprecated:

> This interface is deprecated.
> In favor of [SignInMethodQueryResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/SignInMethodQueryResult) Result object that contains a list of strings that represent authentication provider IDs. For example, [PROVIDER_ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FacebookAuthProvider#PROVIDER_ID) or [PROVIDER_ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GoogleAuthProvider#PROVIDER_ID).

Moreover, the ProviderQueryResult interface is not apart of the [com.google.firebase.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/package-summary) package anymore, hence that error. Here's the solution:

- [How to check for a phone auth user in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156122/how-to-check-for-a-phone-auth-user-in-android/61156915#61156915)

But instead of phone number, check against the email address.

Comment: Thank you @Alex This Solution has worked for me,