# Firebase phone auth verification after app update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not going to paste any code because I receive the desired behavior when a user creates account with a phone number in firebase auth.

My problem is after an app update, `firebaseUser.getCurrentUser` is null despite the fact that the user is already signed up.

My question:
How do I mimic a behavior like WhatsApp which doesn't require the user to always go through OTP after every app update?

Iv tried using authState:

```
auth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuth -> {
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
      if(user == null)
          signUp()     });
```

Hoping after update user won't be null. But it's always null after updating the app.

Comment: Use an [AuthStateListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth).

Comment: I'm doing exactly that but the listener returns me a null user. The reference you've provided doesn't address how the auth can survive app reinstall (update)

Comment: Without seeing the code that produces that behavior, it's hard to say why you got `null`. So it's better to provide the code directly in your question.

Comment: It seems that the app updating is wiping the refresh token credentials

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I didn't realize is that I was trying to mimic an update behavior by installing and uninstalling the app.  Turns out token credentials are lost in the process. I just assumed Firebase attaches to the device identity some how, some where. I admit I need some instruction