# How do I persist authentication state in my Kotlin firebase app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building a kotlin app using FirebaseAuth and I want to add some custom rules to keep the user signed in for a time even if they are not using the app. All I could find in the docs related to this was for Web applications. `https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence`

Is there anything like this in the docs for Android?

If not, is there a way I can get that functionality?

I was considering using `SharedPreferences` to store authentication state but I get the feeling there is a better way.

Comment: Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth) and see if it helps.

Comment: Is your auth state not persisted? Are explicitly signing out the user?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Thank you! That thread is actually very helpful!

Comment: @AlexMamo No, I am not explicitly signing out the user yet. Do users stay logged in permanently by default?

Comment: Yes, they stay logged in until you sign them out explictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was not aware that firebase users stay signed in until logged out explicitly. Understanding this solved my problem as I didn't have to write code to handle keeping the user signed in.

Answer (score 3):

```
public override fun onStart() {
super.onStart()
        val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            //startActivity
        } else {
            Timber.i("Error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?authuser=0

Comment: If your code worked please confirm.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to set it. Firebase currentuser stay there until you uninstall the application itself or log out. You just need to check whether the currentuser exist or not at the start of activity

```
Val currentUser = Firebase.auth.CurrentUser
if(currentUser1=null){
   Do something....
}
```

Comment: This solved it! Even easier to test it out: if (Firebase.auth.CurrentUser == null) {print('user not logged in');} else {print('user is logged in');}