# Android phone authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

```
Getcurrentuser() return null
```

I facing a problem with getcurrentuser() after signout
Getinstance().signout
In phone authentication
Now currentuser return null how to overcome this?

> I use phone authentication to login into the android app. Everything was working fine until when I use the "sign out" button using `getinstance().signout`
> And after that, when I login again using phone number, I could log into the app, but now I am getting error to get current, it returns null.

How to overcome this problem? I am stuck in it.

Comment: So you say that once you sign out, the FirebaseUser object is null?

Comment: Yes..i dont know how to overcome this problem

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you call [signOut()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signOut()) on an instance of [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth):

> Signs out the current user and clears it from the disk cache.

Which basically means that the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object becomes null. So what you're experiencing is normal behavior. So each time you want to use a FirebaseUser object make sure the user is authenticated. In code you should check that object against nullity. If you however want to take some action when a user signs out, then I recommend you to use an AuthStateListener, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [One time login in app - FirebaseAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)

Comment: Thanx sir…I appreciate your helpful nature but i solved it just to remove signout button because i could not understand

Comment: Sir will you please tell me how to create 3 minute timer which is same for all user. My timer is automatically reset whenever i change fragment

Comment: If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey Shyam. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?